# Extending Bernoulli thompson sampling for slate bandit problems to the contextual setting

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multiarmed-bandit, contextual-bandit, thompson-sampling

I am trying to implement the extension to [Marginal Posterior Sampling for Slate Bandits](https://www.ijcai.org/proceedings/2019/0308.pdf), which is a context-free slate bandit algorithm that uses Thompson sampling with a Bernoulli prior.

I want to follow their extension in section 6 with a generalised linear model trained on each (action, slot) pair. However, the final step of updating the model parameters is just "update the posterior on ζ(j, a) [Li et al., 2010]."

That paper does not talk about GLMs just UCBs.

The procedure described in the Marginal Posterior sampling paper is as follows:

1. Sample from $\zeta(j,a)$
2. Compute slot-action expected reward $v(j,a) = \zeta(j,a)^T \vec{u}$
3. Select each action that has the maximum expected reward per slot, to give a slate of actions $={a_0, a_1, ...}$.

$j$ is the slot number, $a_j$ is the action in slot $j$. $\zeta$ are the GLM parameters per slot action pair and $u$ is the context information such that $\zeta$ has the same shape as $u$.

How do I train the ζ(j, a) parameters? Without context, all you do is keep track of the number of successes per action,slot pair and feed it into the Beta distribution prior.
How do I extend that to include the context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the initial citation ([Li et al., 2010]) might be inaccurate.

To update (,) in the style of Thompson Sampling, a Bayesian regression approach is required. In this scenario, the suitable option would likely be Bayes probit/logit regression.

For Bayes probit regression, this tutorial([Gibbs sampling for Bayesian Binary Probit](https://rpubs.com/cakapourani/bayesian-binary-probit-model)) may be useful.

if you're interested in Bayes logit regression, I recommend looking into the following research articles:

- [Improved Thompson Sampling for Logistic Contextual Bandits](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.07458.pdf)
- [A Tutorial on Thompson Sampling](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ebvr/pubs/TS_Tutorial.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the papers, I understand a bit better now. 
In regards to the Improved thompson sampling paper with PG augmentation, surely this cannot be considered a viable online algorithm since it requires access to the entire reward/context history at each step so the computation cost spirals very quickly. Or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, except for bayes linear regression, which has a conjugate distribution, other algorithms are not very efficient at online updates.